# Is there any method or way to encrypt the view or synonym definition in Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Actually the problem scenario is we are handing over one application to different developer's team altogether.So our management decided to obfuscate the database in such a way that other team's developer and their admins should not be able to see our database objects directly and at the same time the data should be accessible from front end. So in order to resolve this issue I came up with one solution that lets define views in different schema which will call our database tables and to provide additional layer of security on top of that we decided to encrypt the view's definition which was possible  in MS SQL, but after searching tonnes of article we  concluded that its not possible to encrypt view definition in oracle, we tried our level best but no luck. Also we discussed the the table data encryption method using TDE , but management rejected this idea since it requires front end code level changes in order to decrypt the table data, so since application code is also handed-over to developers and hence they will be able to see the code . We also tried wrapping the stored_proc script but there are online tool present to unwrap the code.

What are other practical ways in order to achieve the obfuscation??

Wrapper Class
Symmetric Key Encryption

Comment: It's not possible to obfuscate views so that admins (DBAs) cannot see the code. If you were to scramble it with something, it wouldn't be usable as-is, nor compilable. Even if somehow it was, and you have some dynamic unscrabbler-and-use mechanism, then there's no reason to use real views... store the code as user data, which is far easier to obfuscate.  You can certainly hide your real view code from non-admin users simply by not granting privs on the views and disallowing the `select any dictionary` priv to all non-admin users, but the DBAs cannot be blocked. You have to trust somebody.

Comment: btw, TDE is for encrypting blocks on disk to prevent direct file access/mining at the OS or storage layer. It doesn't hide anything visible through the database itself. My recommendation is to focus on permissions instead of obfuscation.

Comment: Yeah, you can "wrap" code for obfuscation purposes, but it is easily unwrapped. Not sure why TDE would require client code changes, since it is by definition *transparent* to the application and only encrypts application data at rest. As Paul stated, Oracle generally handles things through access control before obfuscation or encryption.

Comment: Paul W. How  permissions can resolve this ??

Comment: You can only see view SQL in `all_views` if you have a privilege on the view. Prevent those users you dont want to see your view SQL from obtaining any privs on the view, and they won't be able to see the definition of the view, or even that it exists at all. Also do not give them `select any dictionary` because you wouldn't want them to hit `dba_views` which bypasses privs.

Comment: a user will always be able to see the sql for their own view

Comment: Paul W. I have tried your approach . I have created a new user , also I have not granted him any privilege neither select any dictionary nor select object . But unfortunately that new user is still able to see and hit on dba_views. How to resolve this issue?